# Button click event works only once asp.net

Tags: asp.net, button, click, row

This is my .aspx code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="passengerBox" CssClass="transparentBox" runat="server">
    <asp:Table ID="passengerDetailsTable" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:Label runat="server" Text="1." /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="name1" CssClass="nameTextbox form-control" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="age1" CssClass="ageTextbox form-control" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:Label runat="server" Text="2." /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="name2" CssClass="nameTextbox form-control" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="age2" CssClass="ageTextbox form-control" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:Label runat="server" Text="3." /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="name3" CssClass="nameTextbox form-control" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="age3" CssClass="ageTextbox form-control" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
    <asp:Button ID="addPerson" runat="server" Text="Add Person" OnClick="addPerson_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

This is my .aspx.cs page:

```
public partial class Pages_Passengers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int count = 3;
    protected void addPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox nameTxtBox = new TextBox();
        TextBox ageTxtBox = new TextBox();

        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            if (i == 1)
                tCell.Text = count.ToString() + ".";
            if (i == 2)
                tCell.Controls.Add(nameTxtBox);
            if (i == 3)
                tCell.Controls.Add(ageTxtBox);
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }
        passengerDetailsTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
    }
}
```

I want to add a new row to the table every time I click the button "addPerson". But this button only works once. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I'm assuming the code has no real purpose but it's just for training.

If you're not using databases the easy way to get data persistency is using session variable (so .. it works but let me remind you it's not always a good idea)

Web form :

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

Your webform now is cleaner because the table will be managed by code behind.

The code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Table _passengerDetailsTable;
    private int _rowCounter = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // a recomandation ... make strong use of comments 

        this.InitTable(); // initializing the table from code behind 

        this._rowCounter = this._passengerDetailsTable.Rows.Count;
    }

    private void InitTable()
    {
        this._passengerDetailsTable = new Table();

        if (Page.IsPostBack) // ok! if page is loaded for the first time we can create table, if we are back by a summit button code will be skipped
        {
            this._passengerDetailsTable = (Table)Session["tblPassengers"]; // get back the Table we stored in a session variable 
        }
        else
        {
            TableRow dr = CreatePassengerDataRow(); // remember DRY Don't Repeat Yourself you are expected to create many rows. Bundle all the needed stuff inside a method 

            // perhaps you should create an header for the table to enhance readibility

            this._passengerDetailsTable.Rows.Add(dr); // add the datarow    

            Session["tblPassengers"] = this._passengerDetailsTable; // store the table state in a session variable 
        }


        this.form1.Controls.Add(_passengerDetailsTable); // add the control to the form             
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// create a new datarow 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="counter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private TableRow CreatePassengerDataRow()
    {

        var dr = new TableRow(); // keeping things easy I'll create a single TableRow               

        // avoid the loop, it make code less readable and has no clear purpose 

        var tc0 = new TableCell();  // counter cell
        tc0.Text = String.Format("#{0}", (this._rowCounter));
        dr.Cells.Add(tc0);

        var tc1 = new TableCell(); // name cell
        tc1.Controls.Add(this.CreateInputTb("name", this._rowCounter)); // DRY again 
        dr.Cells.Add(tc1);

        var tc2 = new TableCell(); // age cell 
        tc2.Controls.Add(this.CreateInputTb("age", this._rowCounter));
        dr.Cells.Add(tc2);
        return dr;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <param name="counter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private TextBox CreateInputTb(string name, int counter)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.ID = String.Format("{0}_{1}", name, counter); // create a tb unique identifier (makes your life easier if you plan to use is data)
        return textBox;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableRow dataRow = this.CreatePassengerDataRow(); // create a brand new role 
        this._passengerDetailsTable.Rows.Add(dataRow); // append the role 
    }
}
```

Enjoy.

Comment: So how do I keep the added rows remain on the page when I click the button again??

Comment: Initialize the table from code behind using the onload event only if Page.IsPostBack false